# Xsl If test To display price gt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Im trying to do a xsl if statement to see can i get prices all above a certain number to display out but i cant get it to work ill post the code to see if anyone can see my mistake i have a dtd and a style sheet but i dont think there is need to pst these

cheers

**XSL :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:template match="/SpecialOffers">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <h1>Special Offer's SuperMarket </h1>
                </center>
                <div id="Title1">
                    <p>Offers Above .99c</p>
                </div>
<div id="content">
                    <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Description</td>
                            <td>Price</td>
                            <td>Offer</td>
                            <td>Number Of items</td>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Hygiene/haircare">
                        <xsl:if test="Price &gt;= 10">
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Offer"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Number_of_items"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>



                        </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>

            </table>
            </div>              
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE SpecialOffers SYSTEM "Offers.dtd">
<!-- <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="SpecialOffersStyleSheet.xsl"?> -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="LoopOffers.xsl"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css" ?>
<SpecialOffers>
    <Hygiene>
        <haircare hid="HS">
            <Price>3.99</Price>
            <Offer> 2 for 1 </Offer>
            <Number_of_items>2</Number_of_items>
            <description>Head and Shoulders</description>
        </haircare>
        <haircare hid="HE">
            <Price>1.99</Price>
            <Offer>30% Off  </Offer>
            <Number_of_items>2</Number_of_items>
            <description>Herbal Essence</description>
        </haircare>
        <haircare hid="L">
            <Price>.99c</Price>
            <Offer> Half Price  </Offer>
            <Number_of_items>1</Number_of_items>
            <description>Loreal</description>
        </haircare>
        <face_body_care>
            <Price>1.50 </Price>
            <Offer>Half Price</Offer>
            <Number_of_items>1</Number_of_items>
            <description>Radox Shower Gel</description>
        </face_body_care>
    </Hygiene>
    <Cleaning_Products>
        <household>
            <Price>2.99</Price>
            <Offer>2 for 1</Offer>
            <Number_of_items>2</Number_of_items>
            <description>Mr Sheen</description>
        </household>
        <detergents>
            <Price>3.50</Price>
            <Offer>25% Off</Offer>
            <Number_of_items>1</Number_of_items>
            <description>Dettol</description>
        </detergents>
    </Cleaning_Products>
    <Grocery>
        <fruit fid="M">
            <name>Mango</name>
            <Price>.99c</Price>
            <Offer>6 for .99c</Offer>
            <weight>2kg</weight>
            <organic></organic>
        </fruit>
        <fruit fid="B">
            <name>Banana</name>
            <Price>1.39c</Price>
            <Offer>1kg</Offer>
            <weight>1kg</weight>
            <organic>Yes</organic>
        </fruit>
        <vegeatables>
            <name>Carrot</name>
            <Price>1.49</Price>
            <Offer>1kg for 1.49</Offer>
            <weight>1kg</weight>
            <organic>No</organic>
        </vegeatables>
        <vegeatables>
            <name>Cabbage</name>
            <Price>.89c</Price>
            <Offer>1</Offer>
            <weight>1kg</weight>
            <organic>Yes</organic>
        </vegeatables>
    </Grocery>
    <Perishables>
        <canned_goods>
            <name>Tuna</name>
            <Price>.99c</Price>
            <Offer>Half Price</Offer>
            <weight>500g</weight>
        </canned_goods>
        <canned_goods>
            <name>Beans</name>
            <Price>1.99c</Price>
            <Offer>6 For 1.99</Offer>
            <weight>500g each</weight>
        </canned_goods>
    </Perishables>
    <Alcholic_Beverages>
        <spirits>
            <name>Vodka</name>
            <Price>14.50</Price>
            <Offer>Half Price</Offer>
            <ml>70cl</ml>
            <volume_acl>37.5%</volume_acl>
        </spirits>
        <spirits>
            <name>Gin</name>
            <Price>27.50</Price>
            <Offer>20% Off</Offer>
            <ml>1 Litre</ml>
            <volume_acl>37.5%</volume_acl>
        </spirits>
        <spirits>
            <name>Gin</name>
            <Price>27.50</Price>
            <Offer>20% Off</Offer>
            <ml>1 Litre</ml>
            <volume_acl>37.5%</volume_acl>
        </spirits>
        <wine>
            <name>Proseco</name>
            <Price>13.75</Price>
            <Offer>10% Off</Offer>
            <ml>1 Litre</ml>
            <volume_acl>13.5%</volume_acl>
        </wine>
        <largers>
            <name>Heinkein</name>
            <Price>£6</Price>
            <Offer>4 for 6</Offer>
            <ml>500ml</ml>
            <volume_acl>4%</volume_acl>
        </largers>
    </Alcholic_Beverages>
    <Non-Alcholic_Beverages>
        <cordials>
            <can>
                <name>7 Up</name>
                <Price>5.00</Price>
                <Offer>12 Pack</Offer>
                <ml>330</ml>
            </can>
            <bottle>
                <name>Coke</name>
                <Price>1.39</Price>
                <Offer>2 for 1</Offer>
                <ml>1 Litre</ml>
            </bottle>
        </cordials>
        <juice>
            <name>Sunny D</name>
            <Price>.75c</Price>
            <Offer>Half Price</Offer>
            <ml>1 Litre</ml>
        </juice>
    </Non-Alcholic_Beverages>
</SpecialOffers>
```

Comment: Please select **either** XSLT 1.0 **or** XSLT 2.0 - not **both**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your stylesheet does not produce any table rows is that there are no haircare products whose price is greater than or equal to 10 in your source XML.

Your title says **"Offers Above .99c"** - and if you want to show products whose price is above 0.99, you need to make your condition:

```
<xsl:if test="Price &gt;= 1">
```

Note that those products in your XML whose price is .99c will not pass this test - but not because their price is lower than the threshold, but because their price is not a number. To include these prices in the comparison, you would have to remove the currency - for example:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(Price, 'c', '') &gt;= .5">
```

---

The above applies to XSLT 1.0 and will also work with an XSLT 2.0 processor for as long as your stylesheet continues to be tagged as `version="1.0"` as it is now.

Comment: Sorry only got back to replying on this cheers for the help i realised afterwards how much of a simple error it was and i just couldnt spot it for the life of me thanks for the help :)